# Nginx Port Forward Not Triggering Page Code When Using Curl

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant

I have set up port-forwarding on my machine so that it forwards any `localhost:8181` traffic to an endpoint on a VM running on my machine.

For the sake of this question, the endpoint simply runs the following PHP code

```
<?php
    error_log('Loaded');
?>
```

Now, if I go to my browser and hit `localhost:8181`, the code will run and I will see 'Loaded' in my error logs.

However, if I curl the endpoint using curl in the terminal, I can see that I get redirected to the page using `curl -v` however the 'Loaded' never gets error logged, meaning the PHP code isn't being triggered.

What's the cause of this and is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option from curl you're looking is `-L` if there's a redirect made by your server

from man

> -L, --location
>
> (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header
>   and a 3XX response
>          code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or -I, --head, headers from
>   all  requested
>          pages will be shown. When authentication is used, curl only sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes curl to
>   a different host,
>          it won't be able to intercept the user+password. See also --location-trusted on how to change this. You can limit the amount of redirects to  follow
>          by using the --max-redirs option.
>
> When  curl  follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with a
>   GET if the HTTP
>          response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send  the  following  request  using  the
>   same  unmodified
>          method.
>
> You can tell curl to not change the non-GET request method to GET after a 30x response by using the dedicated options for that:
>   --post301, --post302
>          and -post303.

Comment: Much appreciated, this fixed the issue.